# How to stop for loop flowing into next for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I stop aList from flowing into sumIs? I've tried a couple of line breaks after aList's to close it. A break in aList stops the for loop and still flows into the sumIs.

code:

```
aList = ['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']
for x in aList:
    print(x, end = ' ')

sumIs = 0
for number in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    sumIs = sumIs + number
print(sumIs)

prod = 1
for item in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    prod *= item
print(prod)

S = 'lumberjack'
T = ("and", "I'm", "okay")
for char in S:
    print(char, end=' ')
```

print as of now is:

```
spam eggs ham 10
24
l u m b e r j a c k
```

print should be:

```
spam eggs ham 
10
24
l u m b e r j a c k
```

Comment: Please do not "flatten" for loops into one-liners.  Please use 4 spaces for your indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `print()`-call in the loop doesn't print any line returns, you have to print the line return after the loop.

Simply add a `print()` after the loop.

Comment: end = ' ' is still pulling 10 into the same line.

Comment: ha, you literally meant add an empty print() after the for loop body. Thanks!

Comment: @milkIt: Exactly. end=' ' doesn't pull anything in, it's the other way around. Without end=' ' the end will be a newline. So it's not a pull, it's an absence of push.